# How to serialize list property of a dynamic object

Tags: c#, json, dynamic

I have an issue with serialization for a wcf service (JSON output).
I use dynamicobject to return ligth JSON for my REST service.

This code return an empty result (impossible to serialize):

```
public DynamicJsonObject DoWork()
{
    dynamic result = new DynamicJsonObject();
    result.values = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };
}
```

but this code works perfectly

```
public DynamicJsonObject DoWork()
{
    dynamic result = new DynamicJsonObject();
    result.values = 1;
}
```

My DynamicJsonObject class is :

```
[Serializable]
public class DynamicJsonObject : DynamicObject, ISerializable
{
    private IDictionary<String, Object> Dictionary { get; set; }

    public DynamicJsonObject()
    {
        Dictionary = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
    }

    public DynamicJsonObject(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Dictionary = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        var hasKey = Dictionary.ContainsKey(binder.Name);
        result = hasKey ? Dictionary[binder.Name] : null;
        return hasKey;
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        Dictionary[binder.Name] = value;
        return true;
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        foreach (String key in Dictionary.Keys)
        {
            info.AddValue(key.ToString(), Dictionary[key]);
        }
    }
}
```

So I got this error Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE) instead of this JSON result {values: [1,2]}

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is your problem? What issue are you having?

Comment: I get this error : Erreur 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. You should to declare manualy list of serializable.

In my exemple, I can add the attribute KnownType on result object

```
[Serializable]
[KnownType(typeof(List<int>))]
public class DynamicJsonObject : DynamicObject, ISerializable
{
    ...
}
```

the other solution is to use the ServiceKnownType on the wcf service class

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(List<int>))]
public interface IDataService
{
    ...
}
```

For information, you can use generic attribute like KnownType(typeof(List)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<UserDetails> list = new List<UserDetails>();//UserDetails is my class name it has some properties
```

for serialization you can use this code:

```
var objSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string sJSON = objSerializer.Serialize(list);
return list;
```

Comment: this is not the solution because the result is :

    "[1,2]"

instead of 

    [1,2]